# Displaying image too big for screen with opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

I would like some tips on displaying my image on the maximum possible size using imshow. 
I'm being able to show it after binarization, but then, when I use findContours, it displays the image cut in the size of the screen.

Comment: Can you please edit to show your work a bit more in details ? We also need to see the code to try to understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case for `namedWindow`, details [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedwindow). Basically you should change the default window option before you display an image:

```
Mat a_very_big_image = imread("path_to_a_very_big_image");

// WINDOW_NORMAL allows window to be resized
namedWindow("auto resize", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("auto resize", a_very_big_image);
waitKey(0);
```